# The word 's' after our

Tags: grammar

Do we have to put the word 's' after our?

For example,

- Our schools
- Our voices
- Our teachers
- Our surroundings

Comment: I don't follow the question. It's *our school* if there's a single school and *our schools* if there is more than one school. There is nothing in any of these examples that indicates the nouns are singular but having a plural form incorrectly assigned.

Comment: Putting *s* or let's say using the plural form of the noun is not related to the possessive adjective in your examples. You should decide based on the number of the things you are talking about. For example, if "our" refers to the students who go to the same school, you should say "our school", but if each of these students goes to a different school, you should use "our schools".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *our schools, our voices, our teachers, our surroundings*.

No, there is no need to add the *s* after "our" in those examples.

Genitive personal pronouns have two forms: a dependent one which is not marked by -*s*, e.g., *our house* / *their houses* etc.,, and an independent one which is marked by  *s*, e.g., *This house is ours* / *theirs*. Note that the independent form of "my" is the irregular "mine".